# Server error slim framework php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with Slim framework.I tried to display hello world on screen but it gives me the error:

```
 Server run an intern error and couldn't resolve your request.The server is overloaded or it was an error in a script CGI.
 Error 500
```

My index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/hello', function () {
   echo "Hello";
});
$app->run(); ?>
```

and my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
 RewriterULE ^ index.php [QSA, L]
```

I also modify in httpd.conf with the lines:

```
 <Directory />
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

So when I write http://localhost/monologTree/hello it gives me the error from the start. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F` be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` instead ?

Comment: it doesn't fix the pb

Answer (score 0):

Check your composer.json file. I think you have installed slim 3. Then Try to instantiate slim like this

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Slim\App();
```

Check this [example](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/simple-rest-api-with-slim-micro-framework/) for properly use Slim from installation.

The 2nd solution is Find the file called httpd.conf, it should be located in
**XAMPPInstallDirectory\apache\conf**

Open with notepad and find this line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Remove the **#**, save it, restart apache (if running).

Comment: I've checked. it's 2.6

Comment: change the autoload line as i suggested then reply

Comment: When I first open the httpd.conf the line was already like yours. :(

Comment: So is not that the pb

Comment: Can you comment the  <Directory /> tag from httpd.conf file? Ten check if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128834/discussion-between-shahroze-nawaz-and-adiiia).